# Is it possible to solve this type of differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving a calculus problem, I encountered a type of differential equation that I had never seen before.  This is the differential equation:

$f'(x)=\frac { x }{ f(x) } -\frac { 1 }{ f(1) } $

Is this equation solvable or not.  If it is, could someone please explain how to solve it.

Comment: $\frac1{f(1)}$ is just a number (that you'll want to make sure is equal to $\frac1{f(1)}$ at the end). Let's call it $a$. Then we can [literally ask a computer if the equation is solvable](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+f%27%28x%29%3Dx%2Ff%28x%29-a+solvable%3F) and find out the solution, and what named category of differential equation this falls under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{f(x)}-\frac{1}{f(1)}$$
$$f'(x)f(x)+\frac{f(x)}{f(1)}=x$$
Now this is a non-linear first order ODE. They do not always have a nice solution

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=yy%27%2Bay%3Dx